# karma start Cannot find module 'jasmine-core'

Tags: module, jasmine, karma-runner

I was getting the following error when I ran "karma start"

> module.js:340
>       throw err;
>       ^
>   Error: Cannot find module 'jasmine-core'
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
>       at Function.require.resolve (module.js:384:19)
>       at initJasmine (/usr/lib/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/index.js:8:42)
>       at Array.invoke [as 0] (/usr/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/di/lib/injector.js:75:15)
>       at get (/usr/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/di/lib/injector.js:48:43)
>       at /usr/lib/node_modules/karma/lib/server.js:137:20
>       at Array.forEach (native)
>       at Server._start (/usr/lib/node_modules/karma/lib/server.js:136:21)
>       at invoke (/usr/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/di/lib/injector.js:75:15)
>       at Server.start (/usr/lib/node_modules/karma/lib/server.js:101:18)
>       at Object.exports.run (/usr/lib/node_modules/karma/lib/cli.js:231:26)
>       at Object. (/usr/lib/node_modules/karma/bin/karma:3:23)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)

Does anyone know why this is happening?  I was running karma in a VM.  I tried several npm install commands and nothing worked.  After I shutdown my machine for the night and came back the next day the problem went away and everything is working again. So, I'm not blocked anymore.. Anyone have some thoughts on what could be happening?

Comment: Something probably changed your system path and the restart loaded it fresh.

Comment: Where you able to get your problem solved? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35993875/error-cannot-find-module-jasmine-core

Comment: Possibly related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33870520/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33870520/)?

Answer (score 69):

I solved using `npm install jasmine-core --save-dev`

Comment: Solved my issue

Answer (score 49):

try install `jasmine-core` globally ([Jasmine on NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-core)). 
use `npm install -g jasmine-core`

Comment: I tried both these answers, but still getting this error, mind a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35993875/error-cannot-find-module-jasmine-core

Comment: `npm install jasmine-core --save-dev` this is better than global

Answer (score 8):

Even with `karma` and `karma-jasmine` installed in the local project's `node_modules` you must still `npm install jasmine`.

#### So for a fresh Karma project:

1. `npm install karma karma-jasmine jasmine` to install the required modules locally.

Optionally add `--save-dev` to write to your `package.json`.
Note these do not need to be `-g` globally installed here.

2. `karma start`

This step requires you to have Karma installed globally (`sudo npm install -g karma`).

Answer (score 8):

Navigate to folder:

`cd node_modules\karma-jasmine`

Run:

`npm install`

This should download the required dependencies and fix the issue.

Comment: Wow... that is just bad. Works though.

Answer (score 0):

Also, it is important to know the installation path where do you have karma.conf.js file.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem, and have tried every suggestion on the page without it fixing the problem. Well, I haven't yet rebooted, so I'll try that next, but I have closed my shell (git-bash) and re-opened it in case it was an environment variable problem. Something is wrong here and I don't think the problem has been identified yet.

Comment: Rebooting did not help, so I'm completely stuck!

Comment: Solved (for me, at least): I had run 'npm install -g karma' to get the karma command, but had to uninstall that, then run 'npm install -g karma-cli'. After that, 'karma start' works!