# Npm install cannot find module 'semver'

Tags: javascript, node.js, mean-stack

I can't use `npm install` using the command prompt in NodeJS. I'm getting these errors when running `npm install`:

```
module.js:339
    throw err;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module 'semver'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:337:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:287:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\l
ib\config\defaults.js:6:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
```

Comment: I had the same problem Alternatively, you can use yarn, instead of npm

Comment: Are you using yarn to install the package.json ?

Comment: Just reinstall npm

Comment: Different, but possibly related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53545800#62740853](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53545800#62740853) -- Helpful?

Comment: I stumbled upon the issue when I upgraded node in my ubuntu and closed terminal. But I forgot to close and open Visual Studio again. Once reopened, the issue went away. :)

Comment: Similar as @sangam: I just restarted Linux, and then it worked.

Comment: This workd for me: `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules` then `sudo rm -rf ~/.npm` then exit SSH and reconnect.

Answer (score 459):

I had the same error. `npm uninstall npm -g`, `rm -rf node_modules` didn't help me, because when I tried I was getting `Error: Cannot find module 'semver'`. But I solve my problem with these steps (this will delete other global modules you may be using):

- `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules`
- `sudo rm -rf ~/.npm`
- `brew uninstall --force node`
- `brew install node`

Hope this will help those who are getting a similar problem.

Comment: Used this on two different machines running El Capitan, worked in both cases.

Comment: Use `brew uninstall --force node` to remove all versions

Comment: I didn't use  `brew uninstall --force node` at first try, it's going to break node and npm. Looks like if you have multiple version node installed, really need `--force`

Comment: just install npm again. `curl -0 -L https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh` after remove npm folder

Comment: This also fixed my issue on Mac OS Sierra

Comment: I've tried this solution, but it didn't fixed in my case. I've fixed with solution shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30043872/docker-compose-node-modules-not-present-in-a-volume-after-npm-install-succeeds)

Comment: worst part is taht every time I want to update node I have to go through this process of completely removing node, and then adding it back. It's getting silly

Comment: This worked for me after upgrading to Node v8.0.0/npm v5.0.x

Comment: If Yarn is already installed, `brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies node` works for me where `brew uninstall --force node` didn't.

Comment: `brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies --force node` on Sierra 10.12.5 works for me

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you! Does anyone know why this error arose in the first place? Something about the node / npm version? One day I woke up and couldn't `npm run serve` as I had been routinely ... I'm not aware of anything at all that might have caused this change. Anyway, glad to be up and npm running again.

Comment: Its my fault for blindly pasting commands, but `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules` caused me to lose global modules I use such as gulp and selenium server. **Be weary of this**

Comment: Yep - just keep in mind this deletes all global modules, such as Ionic or Gulp. Will have to reinstall them with `npm i (module) -g`

Comment: Works great!
I recommend to use nvm instead of brew.

Comment: I didn't have to delete all my global modules. Following the instructions above, I replaced this "sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules" with this "sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node". Basically I just added "/node" and it magically worked for me. Again, you have to still follow the instructions above :)

Btw, thanks @artiebits for the solution! :)

Comment: Save yourself 10 minutes - try this answer first: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49422151/524537

Comment: Win10: removing app's node_modules and package-lock.json, then npm install - solved issue for me.

Comment: @BojanRadivojevicBomber I with I saw your comment earlier, the above solution didn't work or at least was stuck at "make install" and now I 'have to reinstall every single package :(

Comment: I just had a similar issue, but with the ui5 command installed through npm. I think i had some versioning issues, but clearing the entire npm seems to have fixed it. Thanks! (for reference, I was trying to use the @ui5/cli package)

Comment: Someone please explain why it worked , for me also it worked

Comment: `curl -0 -L https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh` was needed. Also incase you need some specific version of node done forget to mention it like this `brew install node@16.4.2`

Answer (score 270):

if you are in Linux server exit from the server and re ssh

Comment: This also works if you are on a local terminal session (tested on Ubuntu 20)! One year later, npm still has this issue...

Comment: Had this issue after using n to change the node version (in WSL), this answer should be higher rated ;)

Comment: Also worked for me on ubuntu on wsl2

Comment: This worked like a charm, but the answer would be more useful if it explained why this worked.

Comment: Always try the simpler answer first. Reinit VSCode and terminal fixed it for me. Using Ubuntu.

Comment: Yup, Debian local machine, had just installed and upgraded npm. Closing the terminal and open new one refreshed something, and (npm install) it just worked. Without uninstalling/re-installing anything. Great.

Comment: worked on orangepi 5 running armbian.
I had the thread error after following this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19584407 for upgrading my nodejs to the latest stable version

Comment: Worked for me running Ec2 Ubuntu Jammy 22.04

Comment: From all the answers and re-installations I've done, I can't believe this actually worked! Thanks a lot!

Comment: you can do this via "hash -r" as well, assuming bash, and "rehash" assuming zsh. It's about path updating

Comment: It worked, thanks, Ubuntu]

Comment: Ridiculous that this works given its Unix (confirmed on Ubuntu)....

Answer (score 108):

I'm facing the same issue here.

If this occurs right after you run `brew install yarn` try running `yarn global add npm` and voilà - fixed!

Comment: This solution worked great for me and is infinitely simpler than the alternatives here. I think yarn can mangle npm if the install gets a permissions/access error during upgrade/install.

Comment: This should be the correct answer. The other method can break things and doesn't address what really needs to happen, which is telling yarn how to use node. Update: Wait, I still get the above error. :(

Answer (score 65):

On MS Windows, the solution is to remove `%APPDATA%\npm` and reinstall [`node`](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)

Comment: I wish I could double-up this vote for Windows. There's a gotcha: The AppData directory was hidden by default, so I didn't think it was actually installed at this location.

Comment: On windows just _repair_ no need to reinstall

Comment: @samayo On Windows where you install there is a repair option. Sorry this was a contextual comment.

Comment: This approach worked for me as well on my 64-bit Windows 8.1 Enterprise laptop. I had to delete both the "npm" as well as the "npm-cache" folders, followed by an uninstall and a new node installation.

Comment: Please can somebody provide a full concise and exhaustive tutorial on how to achieve this on Microsoft Windows?

Comment: i deleted npm and npm-cache from c:/user/myusername/appData/Roaming also by default it was hidded so first show hidden folders and then reinstaled node

Answer (score 65):

On Ubuntu, if you would rather manage Node through the default repositories using `apt`, it's best to install both `nodejs` and `npm` this way.

It's very likely that the version of npm you are using is expecting `semver` in a specific place that is not aligned with the version of Node JS you have installed. If there is only one version of `nodejs` and only one version of `npm`, and they are both installed using the default repositories, this should work perfectly.

Here is my best guidance for getting Node and npm working using the main Ubuntu repositories:

0. `sudo apt-get purge nodejs --auto-remove` and `sudo apt-get purge npm --auto-remove`
1. `whereis node`: remove all the versions of node, one at a time. Repeat until this command returns a blank after `node:`.
2. `sudo apt-get install nodejs`
3. `node --version`: should return `... no such file or directory`
4. `nodejs --version`: should return `v1x.x.x`. This is the version installed by `apt`. It will probably be less recent that the latest version available on the Node JS website.
5. `sudo apt-get install npm`
6. `npm --version`: it will use the `nodejs` installed by `apt` and work correctly.

Comment: I found this answer is useful for Ubuntu 20.x.x in aws....

Comment: Step number 1 did the trick, awesome. Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: having a problem at step #3 on ubuntu 20.10 - as soon as I execute step 2 node starts to exist

Comment: This answer helped me tremendously. For anyone using virtual machines with Ubuntu 20.04, I successfully installed latest node (v 16) installed with npm (v 7) using nvm. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-up-node-on-ec2-instance.html

Comment: 2b: do the same with npm?

Comment: @Gauthier - Yes, do the same with npm (step 5).

Comment: in my case; step 1 whereis node still return one entry in /usr/local/bin/node; which i deleted using sudo rm /usr/local/bin/node

Comment: On Linux Mint after installing node, both node and nodejs respond with the same version (v10.19.0), this is because node installation also creates a link called nodejs. However npm returns a different version (6.14.4) which I assume is ok.

Comment: On the second step, nvm could also be a soltuion.

Comment: This was useful for me in seeing where the problem was.  Instead of uninstalling and re-installing the default Ubuntu version, I just uninstalled the Ubuntu version and installed everything through Node Version Manager (nvm).

Answer (score 47):

I had this too, after running `brew install yarn` yesterday. At least, everything was fine up until then.

I ran `rm -rf node_modules` and tried to reinstall, but no `npm` command was working.

In the end I took the rather simple step of reinstalling Node via the official Node installer for Mac OS X.

https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Everything is fine now. Just went back to the directory, ran `npm install` and it's done the trick.

Comment: `npm install` did it for me. I was installing all of the dependencies one by one but `npm install` did them all at once. Thanks.

Comment: I also had this occur to me after a `brew install yarn`

Comment: simple reinstalling node.js from official osx installer helped. thanks!

Comment: it happened to me after ```brew install yarn``` as well!! what the heck, yarn

Answer (score 38):

I had the same problem, the way i solved it was by executing

```
PATH="$PATH"
```

in terminal, problem was the terminal kept the old path of nodejs instead of using the new one.

Answer (score 35):

On **Arch Linux** what did the trick for me was:

```
sudo pacman -Rs npm
sudo pacman -S npm
```

Comment: I had to use `sudo pacman -Rdd` to remove ignoring the dependencies, but it did not solve the issue for me. Installing semver from the arch packages in Mathias Braun's answer did.

Answer (score 18):

Having just encountered this on Arch Linux 4.13.3, I solved the issue by simply reinstalling `semver`:

```
pacman -S semver
```

Answer (score 13):

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/local/share/man/man1/node* ~/.npm
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node*
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/node*
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/include/node*

sudo apt-get purge nodejs npm
sudo apt autoremove
```

Then install node and npm

[original answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1170408/978755)

Comment: Duplicate from https://askubuntu.com/questions/1152570/npm-cant-find-module-semver-error-in-ubuntu-19-04

Answer (score 12):

Actually, it is taking the reference of previously stored modules.

Solution:Delete the npm-cache/npm folder in the installation directory of nodejs.
In windows, it is in C:/User/Username/Appdata/Roaming/npm(or npm_cache).
and try to install again.

Same thing to do in any OS.

Comment: That's it. I uninstalled node. Then deleted both `npm` and `npm_cache` from `/Appdata/Roaming`. Then installed node again. Seems cache to be blamed there.

Answer (score 11):

Just uninstall node js then reinstall it using nvm. Your problem will be solved. I am a debian 10 user.

To install `nvm`, follow the instructions in the [latest nvm installation script](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#install--update-script) or run the following (potentially out of date) command:

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.5/install.sh | bash
```

after executing the command. close your terminal and reopen then run this command to install node js latest version.

```
nvm install --lts
```

now check the node version by running `node -v`

Comment: This was the fix for me on a Raspbian v10. None of the other solutions worked.

Comment: I think this should be the correct solution, because like the official site said:
["We strongly recommend using a Node version manager like nvm to install Node.js and npm. We do not recommend using a Node installer, since the Node installation process installs npm in a directory with local permissions and can cause permissions errors when you run npm packages globally."](https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-node-js-and-npm)
then after installing nvm, you can install the latest long term support version just with "nvm install --lts".

Answer (score 9):

In my case on macOS(10.13.6), when I executed the following command

```
npm install -g react-native-cli
```

I got this error

```
Error: Cannot find module 'semver'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/unsupported.js:2:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
```

The error got resolved after executing the command

```
yarn global add npm
```

proposed by @Ashoor

Comment: Worked for me _after_ purging the OS (Ubuntu) versions of `nodejs` and `npm`, which are 5 major versions behind the official installer versions.

Answer (score 7):

Just make sure `semver` is installed: `npm install -g semver`

Comment: npm is not working, so you can't install semver through npm.

Best solution is to use yarn to install npm or missing packages

Comment: @NFpeter I had exactly the same problem as stated in the question and fixed it this way, so npm did work (in my case at least).

Answer (score 7):

For me, this happened after I installed yarn globally.
To resolve this issue, install npm using yarn and done.

```
yarn global add npm
```

Answer (score 6):

I got same error and I solved it.

delete **package-lock.json** file and **node_modules** folder then `npm install`

Answer (score 6):

For arch linux

```
sudo pacman -Rsc -n nodejs
sudo pacman -Sy nodejs
sudo pacman -Sy npm
```

Found here: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/15558

Answer (score 5):

On Windows, downloading [Node's MSI](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) again and doing a 'Repair' worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue but it was caused by a broken `package-lock.json` file.

Deleting `package-lock.json` and running `npm install` again fixed it for me.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me on Ubuntu (latest version dated Oct/2020)

I had to first get code from the bash source:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | sudo -E bash -
```

This got the latest version of node which updated my libraries and got rid of the 'semver' error.

Answer (score 4):

First you can try close current terminal tab and open new its work fine

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33005431)

Comment: This is the answer. lol

Answer (score 4):

This issue usually comes when node js and npm versions are not compatible.
To fix this in Ubuntu (my version was 20)

1. Uninstall node js and npm.

   - apt remove npm
   - apt remove nodejs
   - which node (it will return node js files path)
   - Delete node directory
2. Install NVM

   - [Installation](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#user-content-installing-and-updating)
3. Install node

   - nvm install  e.g. nvm install 8.16
   - Above command will itself install node js and its compatible NPM.

Comment: Works fine, same problem in ubuntu server 22.04.

Answer (score 3):

just remove your **node_modules**

```
rm -rf node_modules
```

than

```
yarn
```

or

```
npm install
```

Answer (score 3):

Just a reminder of executable `npm` execute via `node` env:

```
xb@dnxb:/tmp$ type -a npm
npm is /usr/bin/npm
npm is /bin/npm
xb@dnxb:/tmp$ realpath /usr/bin/npm /bin/npm
/usr/share/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
/usr/share/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
xb@dnxb:/tmp$ 
xb@dnxb:/tmp$ head -1 /usr/share/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

I can check which node is chosen by `type -a`, the first line has the most priority, i.e. I can get same error if I run `/usr/local/bin/node /usr/share/npm/bin/npm-cli.js`, but no error if I run `/usr/bin/node /usr/share/npm/bin/npm-cli.js`:

```
xb@dnxb:/tmp$ type -a node
node is /usr/local/bin/node
node is /usr/bin/node
node is /bin/node
xb@dnxb:/tmp$ realpath /usr/local/bin/node
/usr/local/bin/node
xb@dnxb:/tmp$ realpath /usr/bin/node
/usr/bin/node
xb@dnxb:/tmp$ realpath /bin/node
/usr/bin/node
xb@dnxb:/tmp$
```

There are 2 unique node exe based on `realpath`. If you have the similar case, then you need to find out how to remove the undesired/broken node exe, e.g. `sudo rm /usr/local/bin/node` or manipulate env `$PATH`.

Answer (score 2):

Faced this issue when I ran `npm install` using a lower version of node. Then later when I upgraded to latest version of node and ran `gulp`, it has shown this error.

To resolve, deleted node_modules and re-ran `npm install`. Then `gulp` ran fine.

Answer (score 2):

i was getting an error saying Permission Denied after running any 'ng' command (ng --version). I googled for a while and tried clearing npm cache `npm cache verify`, uninstalling my global angular cli (`npm uninstall -g @angular/cli`) and reinstalling Angular/cli (`npm install -g @angular/cli`) etc.. but it would give an error say its already installed. but the node_modules folder here wouldn't have any angular folder.. reinstalled node even then restarted my computer.

ANSWER: Finally I found that the ng.cmd and ng.ps1 files in `C:\Users\JaGoodwin\AppData\Roaming\npm\` here were still there (in npm folder).. even though I did `npm uninstall -g @angular/cli`. those files were causing ng (angular/cli) to think it was still installed. i deleted those files then `npm install -g @angular/cli@8.3.29` (version i need) I then removed my projects node_modules and then ran `npm install` and now can run my angular project using `ng serve`.

[image]

`C:\Users\JaGoodwin\AppData\Roaming\npm\`

Find this by folder searching %APPDATA% in your windows search bar.

Answer (score 2):

Start fresh.

```
brew uninstall --force node
brew install node
```

Answer (score 2):

Just delete (or rename) the cloned repository's version of semver folder:
`"gitClonedRepository/App/node_modules/semver"`

and copy the "semver" folder from
`"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\semver"`

into the application's node_modules folder.

*(if you're on Windows, othervise it must be located somewhere in /usr/local/lib/node_modules).*

Answer (score 2):

All I needed was `sudo rm -rf node_modules/` in the directory I was working in. This happened after I updated my node version with `n lts`

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind
install Yarn.Performs parallel installation resulting in better speed and performance from npm

> ```
>  sudo apt remove yarn
> curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add - 
> echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install yarn -y
> ```

Answer (score 2):

On WSL (so, ~Ubuntu), I faced this problem after having installed both, `nodejs` and `npm` through `apt`, then updated Node using [`n`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n).

I was able to resolve it by completely removing apt's installation of npm: `sudo apt purge npm`.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured this out! Yes, you have to uninstall/delete all files and reinstall. BUT SOME OF THE FILE PATHS ARE TOO LONG TO DELETE DURING THE UNINSTALL PROCESS.  The file paths are so long in Node that they may not be able to be deleted.  You have to rename the file paths.

After uninstalling Node, use Command Prompt, navigate to ...\Appdata\roaming\ (use the path from the error message).  Try to delete the folder with del npm. Then, if it doesn't allow you to delete a folder, start renaming the folders in the file path in the next error message to "a" or something short. You may have to do this for multiple folders along the path.  Then you should be able to delete! Then reinstall node and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it happened while upgrading to gulp 4 from gulp 3 in my project.
So, when I run "gulp watch" command, it was throwing me same error.

It's probably due to version mismatch as compared to my globally installed gulp.

So, either upgrading gulp with "-g" global flag would help, or else I followed this below

However, I used "./node_modules/.bin/gulp watch" in my project. This ensures that all the dependencies that gulp needs are taken from node_modules only.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the /node_modules folder and try again. ;)

You can use `npm rm` to remove it.

You can also check [this issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/588) on GitHub.
To be more specific about unnistal, try to follow [this](https://github.com/npm/npm/blob/master/README.md#uninstalling):

> **Uninstalling**
>
> So sad to see you go.
>
> sudo `npm uninstall npm -g` Or, if that fails,
>
> sudo make uninstall More Severe Uninstalling
>
> Usually, the above instructions are sufficient. That will remove npm,
>   but leave behind anything you've installed.
>
> If you would like to remove all the packages that you have installed,
>   then you can use the npm ls command to find them, and then npm rm to
>   remove them.
>
> To remove cruft left behind by npm 0.x, you can use the included
>   clean-old.sh script file. You can run it conveniently like this:
>
> npm explore npm -g -- sh scripts/clean-old.sh npm uses two
>   configuration files, one for per-user configs, and another for global
>   (every-user) configs. You can view them by doing:
>
> npm config get userconfig   # defaults to ~/.npmrc npm config get
>   globalconfig # defaults to /usr/local/etc/npmrc Uninstalling npm does
>   not remove configuration files by default. You must remove them
>   yourself manually if you want them gone. Note that this means that
>   future npm installs will not remember the settings that you have
>   chosen.

Comment: Updated my answer. Try it now. If it does not work, test something for me. Copy the package.json to another folder and try to use npm install.

Comment: Can you paste your package.json, please?

Comment: {
  "name": "workspace",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.13.2",
    "bson": "^0.2.22",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.5",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "express": "~4.13.1",
    "hbs": "~3.1.0",
    "monk": "^1.0.1",
    "morgan": "~1.6.1",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0"
  },
   "engines": {
    "node": "4.2.2"
}
}

Comment: Have you tried to run npm install with your package.json in another folder?

Comment: i have to uninstall to node.js, after install node.js....i have to create sampleapplication using mean.that time i have to install npm intall command,but i am getting same error...please give some solution to me....

Answer (score 0):

In my case, simply re-running `brew install yarn` fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I faced with same trouble after brew installs yarn on my MacOs Sierra 10.12.6. (And the first try of installation fall after brew update self with a message " Homebrew must be run under Ruby 2.3! You're running 2.0.0. (RuntimeError)". So I re-run it.)

So I use n manager to reinstall npm.

- switch to another node version (for my case to 8.0) by "n" command with empty parameters
- or install new by "n x.x.x" where x.x.x the node version number (i need 6.9.1)
- delete working version by "n rm x.x.x" where x.x.x the node version number. use sudo if need
- install working version by "n x.x.x" where x.x.x the node version number. use sudo if need
- switch by to the working version of node. (see first step for reference)

I think the trouble can be caused that node was installed under sudo for case.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue installing on AWS Linux. I had to install it with `sudo`. So to get around this I followed step 3 from this article (making sure to get the latest version of node)

https://www.hostingadvice.com/how-to/update-node-js-latest-version/

```
wget https://nodejs.org/dist/vx.x.x/node-vx.x.x-linux-x64.tar.xz
tar -C /home/aUser/node --strip-components 1 -xJf node-vx.x.x-linux.x64.tar.xz
```

But installed it to the user's home directory `/home/aUser/node`. Then added that path to my PATH.

`export PATH=/home/aUser/node/bin:$PATH`

After that I was able to do an `npm install` with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issues while running project on higher version of cli. To solve this issue you can simply comment out @angular-devkit/build-angular module and again you have to reinstall it through

> npm install @angular-devkit/build-angular --save

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to get a 'semver' typescript error for the 'import' keyword, check if your file's extension is js instead of ts

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this `Cannot find module 'semver'` error while running `npm install` in WSL1 under Windows 10, with Ubuntu 22.04.2 LRS (jammy) as the Linux installation.

Using `strace` to see what syscalls were made, I found that Node.js was looking for `/usr/share/nodejs/npm/node_modules/semver/package.json`, which didn't exist.  However, that module does appear to exist at the top level, in `/usr/share/nodejs/semver/package.json`.  After some experimentation, I found that adding the top-level directory to Node's search path appears to fix the problem.  This worked for me:

```
NODE_PATH=/usr/share/nodejs npm install
```

Therefore, I've added the environment variable setting to my `~/.bashrc` file:

```
export NODE_PATH=/usr/share/nodejs
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete node_modules folder
2. Restart trminal
3. Run npm whatever

Answer (score -2):

Just check your preinstall scripts if you have one. Sometimes to restrict the versions of `node` and `npm` one needs to run a project.

If that's the case you need to install `semver` manually via `npm install -g semver`