# Upgrade graceful-fs module to a recent version

Tags: node.js, npm

i've a docker container from node:6 official image.
I'd like trying this project: `https://github.com/mozilla/fxa-webrtc-idp`

node version is 6.9.5
npm version is 3.10.10

when i exec `npm test`, this is what appairs:

```
root@3be6ee5c1ab6:/fxa-webrtc-idp# npm test
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info using npm@3.10.10
npm info using node@v6.9.5
npm info lifecycle fxa-webrtc-idp@0.64.0~pretest: fxa-webrtc-idp@0.64.0
npm info lifecycle fxa-webrtc-idp@0.64.0~test: fxa-webrtc-idp@0.64.0

> fxa-webrtc-idp@0.64.0 test /fxa-webrtc-idp
> LOG_LEVEL=error grunt test --node-env=test

(node:354) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. If you are using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version.
Running "copyright:app" (copyright) task

Running "eslint:files" (eslint) task


Running "mochaTest:test" (mochaTest) task


  the route /sign
    ✓ returns a 401 when the request is not authenticated
    ✓ returns a signed assertion when the request is authenticated

  the route /
    ✓ should return version information

  the route /__version__
    ✓ should return version information


  4 passing (44ms)


Running "mochaTest:coverage" (mochaTest) task
  Coverage Summary:
  Name                         Stmts   Miss   Cover   Missing
  -----------------------------------------------------------
  lib/app.js                      22      0    100%   
  lib/logging/summary.js          14      3     79%   14,30,31
  lib/routes/index.js              1      0    100%   
  lib/routes/oauthBegin.js         7      2     71%   20,25
  lib/routes/oauthComplete.js      8      2     75%   18,24
  lib/routes/sign.js              10      0    100%   
  lib/routes/verify.js            16      9     44%   14,23,26,27,29,31,32,35,37
  lib/routes/version.js           52      8     85%   34,35,47,48,60,61,74,75
  ===========================================================
  TOTAL                          130     24     82%


Running "mochaTest:travis-cov" (mochaTest) task
Coverage: 81%
Code coverage below threshold: 81 < 95


Execution Time (2017-02-08 11:46:19 UTC)
loading tasks      1s  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 58%
eslint:files    432ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 25%
mochaTest:test  287ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 16%
Total 1.8s

npm info lifecycle fxa-webrtc-idp@0.64.0~test: Failed to exec test script
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

When i exec `npm ls graceful-fs` this is what appairs:

```
root@3be6ee5c1ab6:/fxa-webrtc-idp# npm ls graceful-fs
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info using npm@3.10.10
npm info using node@v6.9.5
fxa-webrtc-idp@0.64.0 /fxa-webrtc-idp
+-- grunt@0.4.5
| `-- glob@3.1.21
|   `-- graceful-fs@1.2.3 
+-- grunt-conventional-changelog@5.0.0
| `-- conventional-changelog@0.5.3
|   `-- read-pkg@1.1.0
|     +-- load-json-file@1.1.0
|     | `-- graceful-fs@4.1.11 
|     `-- path-type@1.1.0
|       `-- graceful-fs@4.1.11 
+-- grunt-eslint@17.3.1
| `-- eslint@1.10.3
|   `-- file-entry-cache@1.3.1
|     `-- flat-cache@1.2.2
|       `-- graceful-fs@4.1.11 
+-- grunt-jscs@2.7.0
| `-- jscs@2.9.0
|   `-- babel-jscs@2.0.5
|     `-- babel-core@5.8.38
|       +-- output-file-sync@1.1.2
|       | `-- graceful-fs@4.1.11 
|       `-- regenerator@0.8.40
|         `-- commoner@0.10.8
|           `-- graceful-fs@4.1.11 
+-- grunt-nodemon@0.4.1
| `-- nodemon@1.11.0
|   +-- chokidar@1.6.1
|   | `-- readdirp@2.1.0
|   |   `-- graceful-fs@4.1.11 
|   `-- update-notifier@0.5.0
|     `-- configstore@1.4.0
|       +-- graceful-fs@4.1.11 
|       `-- write-file-atomic@1.3.1
|         `-- graceful-fs@4.1.11 
`-- grunt-nsp@2.1.2
  `-- nsp@2.0.1
    `-- nodesecurity-npm-utils@3.0.0
      `-- silent-npm-registry-client@1.0.0
        `-- npm-registry-client@6.3.3
          `-- graceful-fs@3.0.8 

npm info ok
```

How can i solve my problem? Thanks for the support

Answer (score -1):

Try upgrading your npm. It might help, like it did for me with similar kind of error. Please run below command and

npm install npm@latest -g

Comment: thanks.After that, i've tried npm test;this is what appairs now: module.js:471    throw err;
Error: Cannot find module 'semver' at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)  at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)  at Module.require (module.js:497:17)  at require (internal/module.js:20:19)  at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/unsupported.js:2:14)  at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)  at Module.load (module.js:487:32)  at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)  at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)

Comment: Please follow below link for the same error. Thanks   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33870520/npm-install-cannot-find-module-semver