# "module.js:557 throw err" when running npm from terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

when I run npm from terminal I get this error and nothing else. no npm command is working, all of them are giving the same error and I can't even install programs that are depending on nodejs.

> $ npm module.js:557 throw err; ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module 'semver'
>
> at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:555:15)
>
> at Function.Module._load (module.js:482:25)
>
> at Module.require (module.js:604:17)
>
> at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
>
> at Object. (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/unsupported.js:2:14)
>
> at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
>
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
>
> at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
>
> at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
>
> at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)

Comment: Your npm module may be corrupted or some not suitable module versions are installed. I heard similar problems earlier. Take a look at those urls for workaround solutions at least... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33870520/npm-install-cannot-find-module-semver  and https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/issues/302

Comment: I updated semver manually and the problem was fixed, but i got another error "cb() never called" so i was fed up and switched to yarn package manager. Either way, thanks bruh!

Comment: See if [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53545800#62740853](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53545800#62740853) helps.

Answer (score 6):

This did the trick for me (I'm using OSX)

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules
sudo rm -rf ~/.npm
brew uninstall --force node
brew install node
```

Comment: Worked perfectly.