# I want to install sass using npm, but it throws err: Cannot find module "semver"

Tags: npm, sass, npm-install

I am trying to install `sass` with the following command:

`npm install node-sass --save-dev`

But I am receiving the following error:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:626
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'semver'
Require stack:
- /usr/share/npm/lib/utils/unsupported.js
- /usr/share/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:623:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:527:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:681:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/unsupported.js:2:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:785:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:641:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:681:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/unsupported.js',
    '/usr/share/npm/bin/npm-cli.js'
  ]
}
```

I have tried uninstalling/reinstalling `npm` but this didn't resolve my error.

So I have tried the following to see if this would help:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/node_modules/
sudo rm -rf ~/.npm
brew uninstall --force node
brew install node
```

But the error still persists.. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could try the following steps and seeing if they resolve your issue:

1. Remove your `package-lock.json` file if it exists. It may have gotten out of sorts and is causing locking issues for `npm`.

   `rm package-lock.json`
2. Retry the steps you listed, but instead of removing the `node_modules` directory from  the `/usr/lib/node_modules` directory try removing the `node_modules` directory from  `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` directory.

The steps would be as follows, for more detailed information see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33870520/npm-install-cannot-find-module-semver):

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules
sudo rm -rf ~/.npm
brew uninstall --force node
brew install node
```

3. Lastly, if all else fails try installing `Node` from official [documentation](https://nodejs.org/en/)

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: @KonulAliyeva  Glad it helped, please accept my answer

Answer (score 0):

(in ubuntu)

1.- sudo apt install yarn

2.- sudo apt install curl

3.- < look at https://deb.nodesource.com the last version> (now 12):

4.- curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo -E bash -sudo apt-get install -y nodejs

5.- sudo npm install npm@latest -g

6.- npm -init or npm -version