# how to fix the problem when i run any command regarding to npm it shows error

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

when I use the command any command associated with npm, it's not working
how to fix the problem. can anyone please help me to solve the problem.
I used the commands

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

after that, I get problems in npm

```
npm -v
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'semver'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename 
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
at Object.<anonymous> 
(/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/unsupported.js:2:14)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js 
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
```

Comment: try reinstalling the npm.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Npm install cannot find module 'semver'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33870520/npm-install-cannot-find-module-semver)

Comment: Try reinstalling: these steps will help. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036806/how-to-remove-npm-and-reinstall-npm-completely-in-18-04

Comment: i followed the steps . but i can't get anything from (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33870520/npm-install-cannot-find-module-semver) @sandrooco

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I solved this problem by uninstalling node_modules and then deleting both the `npm` and `npm-cache` folders in `%APPDATA%`and finally installing the complete node_moodules again.

You can use these steps to remove node_modules:

- `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules`
- `sudo rm -rf ~/.npm`
- `brew uninstall --force node`
- `brew install node`

I hope this will help to solve your problem.