# npm cannot find module 'semver' after reinstall

Tags: ubuntu, npm, semantic-versioning

I am using ubuntu 19.04.

I am getting following error, when trying to do anything with npm

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'semver'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/unsupported.js:2:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
```

I have tried to apply different solutions from SO, but unfortunately they have not worked.

It started happening after reinstalling NPM because of some errors I unfortunately cannot recreate.

What I have tried

```
sudo apt purge nodejs
sudo apt autoremove
```

after these two steps, npm is uninstalled.

```
npm -v
bash: /usr/bin/npm: No such file or directory
```

I proceed to

```
sudo apt install nodejs
```

However the error occurs even after I have purged the files

```
User@User:/$ node -v
v10.16.3
User@User:/$ npm -v
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'semver'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/unsupported.js:2:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
```

I have also tried following

```
sudo apt purge npm
sudo apt purge nodejs
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt install npm
sudo apt install nodejs
```

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules
sudo rm -rf ~/.npm
brew uninstall --force node
brew install node
```

It still yields the same error. The global files should be uninstalled with both of these approaches.

To be certain I have searched the computer with and deleted anything if it looked like something relevant to node or npm.

```
sudo find / -type f -name "node"
sudo find / -type f -name "node_modules"
sudo find / -type f -name "npm"
```

It is if something is carried on through the purging, perhaps some files communication with NPM yielding the error.

Answer (score 15):

I had a similar issue and reinstalling works for me. this straightforward approach works fine for me. founded [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1170408/1463320)

First, remove old staff

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/local/share/man/man1/node* ~/.npm
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node*
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/node*
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/include/node*

sudo apt-get purge nodejs npm
sudo apt autoremove
```

then, Download the latest tar.xz NodeJS file from [official site](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)

```
tar -xf node-v#.#.#-linux-x64.tar.xz
sudo mv node-v#.#.#-linux-x64/bin/* /usr/local/bin/
sudo mv node-v#.#.#-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/ /usr/local/lib/
```

Where #.#.# is the version you downloaded.

finally, Verify installation using

```
node -v
npm -v
```

Comment: The perfect solution for a full removal and reinstall

Comment: Best answer on that subject. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

Try

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -
apt-get update
apt-get install nodejs
```

You might also want to check out the answers here: [Npm install cannot find module 'semver'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33870520/npm-install-cannot-find-module-semver)