# Cannot find module 'semver'

Tags: node.js

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^
```

/*am finding this error even after remoning installed node*/
Error: Cannot find module 'semver'
Require stack:
- /usr/share/nodejs/npm/lib/utils/unsupported.js
- /usr/share/nodejs/npm/lib/cli.js
- /usr/share/nodejs/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
at Object. (/usr/share/nodejs/npm/lib/utils/unsupported.js:1:16)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1097:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19) {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: [
'/usr/share/nodejs/npm/lib/utils/unsupported.js',
'/usr/share/nodejs/npm/lib/cli.js',
'/usr/share/nodejs/npm/bin/npm-cli.js'
]
}

```
Node.js v17.4.0
```

Comment: We need more context. Is it installed? Could you post here the dependencies defined in the package.json file?

Comment: Please add more explanation, this doesn't give enough information for we to understand the problem

Comment: @HasipTimurtas he gave you an error message. What more do you want? Either you know why the error occurred, or you don't know the error occurred.

Comment: It appears that there has been a few people who have received this error, each person who has asked about it has had Node `^v17.3.0`. I think it might be that the file structure in node v17 doesn't come with NPM, or something, but IDK really, but I am going to try and reproduce the problem RN.

Answer (score 0):

it works for me

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -
apt-get update
apt-get install nodejs
```

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57959154/)

Answer (score -3):

did you installed semver module ?

You can try to install semver with command:

```
npm install semver --save
```

Comment: Its very likely that in his situation the `semver` module will not install