# Why does npm throw an "einvalidtagnme" error when trying to install packages depending on nodejs?

Tags: node.js, npm, idyll

I have been trying to install [idyll](https://github.com/idyll-lang/idyll) on my laptop (running on Linux Mint). However I always get this error:

npm ERR! code EINVALIDTAGNAME

npm ERR! Invalid tag name ">=^16.0.0": Tags may not have any characters that encodeURIComponent encodes.

I am pretty new to coding - so maybe this is a trivial issue but googling didn't provide me with any hints. I tried completely uninstalling and reinstalling nodejs and npm as suggested in [Npm install cannot find module 'semver'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33870520/npm-install-cannot-find-module-semver) but that didn't help.

Does somebody have an idea what I could do to get this running?

Comment: have you tried installing it with `npm install -g idyll`?

Comment: Yes, the above error is exactely what I get when I run `npm install -g idyll` :/

Comment: Just in case, check this out: https://github.com/idyll-lang/idyll/issues/694
Could you use node v14 to try to install this?

Comment: Thanks a lot @germanio, I guess that was the issue...