# Cant see npm version on ubuntu because of Error: Cannot find module 'semver'

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I reinstalled ubuntu on my machine and after that installed node, react, npm,  when i tried to start old project and run into same error when i started the project but also when i tried to see version of npm.

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:927
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'semver'
Require stack:
- /usr/share/npm/lib/utils/unsupported.js
- /usr/share/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:924:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:769:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:996:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/unsupported.js:2:14)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1092:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1121:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:996:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
   requireStack: [
    '/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/unsupported.js',
    '/usr/share/npm/bin/npm-cli.js'
  ]
}
```

I uninstalled and installed npm again but it didnt help

Answer (score 0):

Try this link [anotehr SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33870520/npm-install-cannot-find-module-semver)

Basically what they are doing is the below steps:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules
sudo rm -rf ~/.npm
brew uninstall --force node
brew install node
```

replace `brew` with respective package manager

Comment: look up at that but: Unable to locate package brew

Comment: How did you installed node?

Comment: sudo apt install nodejs

Comment: Can you check how to uninstall nodejs that is installed via `apt`...and try to install node using `nvm` which is a better tool for even installing multiple node versions

Answer (score 0):

You generally don't need to install `npm` separately. `npm` is bundled with `node` and the version that is bundled will generally work with the version of `node` you are running. If you install `npm` separately, you run the risk of installing an incompatible version of `node`.

So uninstall `npm`. See if you still have an `npm` available. If not, uninstall and reinstall `node`. Do not install `npm` separately (unless it is using `npm` itself to update to a newer version of `npm` with `npm install -g npm`.)