# Npm install not completing. How do i fix the problem

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

It's been 30 minutes but still not uploaded. How do i fix the problem
[MY PROBLEM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZwvo.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can do following steps which possibly will fix this.

1. Press `Ctrl + 'C'` to stop the process.
2. Delete the `npm_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` file and run `npm cache clean --force`.
3. Reinstall the modules with `npm install`.

Comment: `node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933   const err = new Error(message);               ^  Error: Cannot find module 'semver'` Not working :(

Comment: You can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41000891/13876368).

Answer (score 1):

you can reinstall nodejs  or use npm update to fix this if it doesn't work then check the documentation of the library

Comment: I tried them all but it didn't work

Comment: have you tried to reinstall your nodejs @SinanTosun and ```npm audit fix --force```

Comment: Yes. I tried many times

Comment: @SinanTosun try to install another package if it installs completely then something is wrong with the package if it also stops then visit this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16873973/npm-install-hangs

Answer (score 0):

try to remove the node_modules directory and the package-lock.json file and reinstall by npm i

this might help

Comment: `node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933
  const err = new Error(message);
              ^

Error: Cannot find module 'semver'` Not working :(

Comment: @SinanTosun
as the other commentators said and after searching for the new error. you have to reinstall your nodejs on your machine

check out the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33870520/npm-install-cannot-find-module-semver

Answer (score 0):

after launching the npm install command, npm will read the package.json file, precisely in the "scripts" section. it will automatically launch the "install" script if there is one. now if in the configuration you have something like "install": "npm install ".
npm will therefore relaunch the installation command and so on in repetition.

```
"scripts": {
 "build": "npm build --environment=production",
 "start": "npm start",
 *"install": "npm install"* 
 "test": "npm-run-all lint test:*",
},
```