# I Getting Following Console Error: Cannot find module 'semver'

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, package.json

```
C:\Users\Dell\Demo>npm init --yes
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:998
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'semver'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\unsupported.js
- C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
←[90m    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:995:15)←[39m
←[90m    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:841:27)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:19)←[39m
←[90m    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)←[39m
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\←[4mnpm←[24m\lib\utils\unsupported.js:2:14)
←[90m    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)←[39m
←[90m    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)←[39m
←[90m    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:19)←[39m {
  code: ←[32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'←[39m,
  requireStack: [
    ←[32m'C:\\Users\\Dell\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\lib\\utils\\unsupported.js'←[39m,
    ←[32m'C:\\Users\\Dell\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js'←[39m
  ]
}

Node.js v18.12.1
```

I am trying to create a package.json fil but this Error is showing I have already reinstall the node.js and try to add Enviornment Variable path where my node.js is install "C:\Program Files\nodejs" .
but still it  didn't work

Comment: Is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33870520/npm-install-cannot-find-module-semver a solution?

Comment: No I Have removed %APPDATA%\npm from enviormment variable and system and reinstall node but it didnot work.