# Error: Cannot find module 'jasmine-core'

Tags: node.js, testing, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I installed the following for testing:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "jasmine-core": "^2.4.1",
    "karma": "^0.13.22",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.0"
}
```

After running `karma start` I get the following error:

[image]

Doing a search this is the first question with the same problem: [karma start Cannot find module 'jasmine-core'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32846206/karma-start-cannot-find-module-jasmine-core)

However I've tried both answers, installed `jasmine-core` globally and I already did `npm install jasmine-core --save-dev` :(

---

My `test/index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Jasmine Spec Runner</title>
    <link href="testing.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="../app/assets/js/libs/vendors.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../app/assets/js/bundle.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div>
        <header>
            <h1>Jasmine tests for Dashboard</h1>
        </header>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

My `karma.conf.js`

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Mon Mar 14 2016 11:56:04 GMT-0500 (CDT)

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '.',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      'app/assets/js/bundle.js',
      'test/**/*.js'
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
    },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: false,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: true,

    // Concurrency level
    // how many browser should be started simultaneous
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just a guess, but try cleaning the `npm` cache, removing the `node_modules` and reinstalling everything from scratch:

```
$ rm -rf node_modules
$ npm cache clean
$ npm i

$ sudo npm uninstall -g jasmine-core 
$ sudo npm cache clean -f
$ sudo npm i -g jasmine-core
```

Comment: Ok I just tried each step, and still getting the same error. I thought that would work, since I did recently update `nvm` and have the latest node now

Comment: @LeonGaban thanks for checking. I've also included one more step - uninstalling the globally installed `jasmine-core` and installing it again. Check it too please.

Comment: Ok I did that, also updated `nvm` and installed karma and karma-cli globally, removed node_modules and npm install again, now I'm getting a new error lol `Error: No provider for "framework:jasmine"! (Resolving: framework:jasmine)`

Comment: @LeonGaban that's a progress! :) Could you try installing these things globally: `sudo npm install -g karma-cli` and `sudo npm install -g karma-jasmine`?

Comment: Woot, it's running now, now just gotta figure out `Can not load "PhantomJS", it is not registered!
  Perhaps you are missing some plugin?` lol

Comment: Ah Fixed it, needed to install this `phantomjs-prebuilt`

Answer (score 13):

When declaring `karma` in `package.json`, then it's installed as a local dependency within the `node_modules` directory of your project. But running `karma start` from the console executes your globally installed `karma`. So there are two versions of Karma (local & global) and both have a dependency to `jasmine-core`, which needs to get installed.

When getting `Cannot find module 'jasmine-core'` on `karma start`, then the globally installed Karma misses "jasmine-core". So make sure you have this also installed globally. Best is to run the following commands:

```
npm install -g karma
npm install -g jasmine-core
npm install -g karma-jasmine
```

Afterwards you should be able to run `karma start` on a directory which has a `karma.conf.js` file.

You can also use a locally installed Karma. All you need to do is to install it this way:

```
npm install --save-dev karma 
npm install --save-dev jasmine-core
npm install --save-dev karma-jasmine
```

If you have done that, then make sure that you also execute it from it's path in `node_modules`:

```
./node_modules/karma/bin/karma start
```

Comment: or just `npm install -g karma jasmine-core karma-jasmine` :D

Answer (score 2):

If you start karma on the command line within a local directory, you should install `karma-cli` globally instead of `karma`.

**[Reference](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/1488#issuecomment-120385966)**

Answer (score 0):

Simply navigate to the karma-jasmine directory in the node modules:

```
cd node_modules/karma-jasmine
```

and run `npm install`. jasmine-core is in the devDependecies inside the package.json file. Navigate back to your root and re-run

```
karma start karma-conf.js
```

This should eliminate that error.